# Angular google.maps.event.addListener('place_changed', function() {}); not working

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, addeventlistener, eventtrigger, angular-google-maps

I am adding 'place_changed' listener it's not working first time when I search the address while it's working perfectly afterwards. Can anyone tell me what should be done. here is my code. Thanks in advance for your support

```
var events = {
      places_changed: function (searchBox) {
        var gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('map-search-box'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {

          var place = gPlace.getPlace();

          var a =place.geometry.location;

    $scope.myLocation = {
      lng : place.geometry.location.D,
      lat: place.geometry.location.k
    }
    abc = {
      coords: {
        latitude: place.geometry.location.k,
        longitude:place.geometry.location.D
      }

  }
     $scope.drawMap(abc); 
});
```

}

}

Comment: Can you post the whole controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks KayAnn I have solved the issue. Actually I never checked in the function (searchBox) {} searchBox it's object which were proving all the data I required  so here is updated code that is working perfectly

```
var events = {
      places_changed: function (searchBox) {
       var lat = searchBox.getPlaces()[0].geometry.location.k;
       var lgn = searchBox.getPlaces()[0].geometry.location.D;

        $scope.myLocation = {
        lng : searchBox.getPlaces()[0].geometry.location.D,
        lat: searchBox.getPlaces()[0].geometry.location.k
      }

      abc = {
        coords: {
        latitude: searchBox.getPlaces()[0].geometry.location.k,
        longitude:searchBox.getPlaces()[0].geometry.location.D
        } 
       }
           $scope.drawMap(abc); } }
```